# How to develop a magento extension which modifies existing pages?

Tags: magento

I need to develop a magento extension which adds some content to particular pages such as the product view page. More specifically, on product pages, a button/link needs to be added to add the product to a third-party wishlist site.

Now I did some research, and it's not entirely clear what the best approach would be:

1. Use event/observers to intercept the 'core_block_abstract_to_html_after' event and adding my html there if needed
2. Use local.xml in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ to add my blocks on the correct page using either 'reference' or 'update' tags. However, can I package this local.xml in my extension? And if so, will it not possibly overwrite a user's own local.xml.
3. Use Magento Widgets? It looks like widgets need to be added manually to a page in the admin CMS panel, while it would be preferred to have a switch in the admin configuration to disable or enable the inclusion of the extra content.

Ideally, a user of the extension would need to do mininal configuration (or XML editing), and the extension must be compatible with existing layouts or modifications done by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no single answer here, like anything software related it's all a question of what works best for you, your team, and your users, **but** here's a few general rules of thumb.

CMS Widgets are for content management.  You create a widget when you want to create a  simple user interface where store owners can create typed content, which can then be inserted into a page. Not a good choice to distributing an extension that needs to modify a page, or for creating an on/off feature.  The ideal use case is a Magento solution provider creates specific widgets and a widget workflow, and a store owners content people update the widgets and add them to pages while managing a site's content.

The `local.xml` file is for layout updates that are **local** to this specific store/theme, and require little programatic logic.  Your specific mention of adding a `local.xml` to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout` would be a particularly poor choice for an extension you're distributing, as a user would lose this as soon as they added their own `local.xml` file to a theme.  The ideal use case for `local.xml` is a developer working for a store owner (i.e. has a long term relationship with this particular Magento installation) who needs to build new pages or non-management content/interactive modules. Third party extensions shouldn't add anything to `local.xml`.

The official blessed way to distribute an extension that modifies an existing page would be to

1. Create a module
2. Use that module to **add** a **new** layout xml update file (see files like `catalog.xml` in core modules)
3. Use **this** layout update XML file to make your changes

This gives you the same functionally as `local.xml`, but keeps your code separate from a local user's system code.  If you can add your block and implement your feature using only the features of the layout update xml files (`block`, `reference`, `action`, `ifconfig`, etc ..) this is a good choice.

Finally, there's using a `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` observer.  This will let you add a block using pure PHP.  Some PHP developers (myself included) prefer using this method as it's more programmatically transparent than using layout update xml files.  The downside of using this method is if you attempt to grab a reference to a block

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('some_block');
$block->setSomeMethod('foo');
```

and `some_block` doesn't exist, you'll get you a fatal PHP error for calling a method on a non-object.  That means your observers end up having a lot of code like this

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('some_block');
if($block)
{
    $block->setSomeMethod('foo');
}
```

One of the benefits of using layout xml update files is these sorts of error silently fail on a production store (although it's that same silent failure that's maddening when **developing** a feature)

Hope that helps, and good luck!  When in doubt, use the technique that lets your get your job done — you can always re-factor later.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot actually (together with your tutorials)!